# How can you extract Hardware ID using Python?

Tags: python, hardware, extract

How do you extract an HD and Bios Unique ID, using python script?

Answer (score 3):

Go Get Microsoft's [Scriptomatic](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=09dfc342-648b-4119-b7eb-783b0f7d1178&displaylang=en)

Run it, Select the appropriate class from the dropdown (WIN32_BIOS)

It will produce the necessary Python/WMI code for you.
(It will also generate VBScript, Perl, and JScript)

Answer (score 2):

Solutions that come to my mind:

1. use [Win32 Python Extensions](http://python.net/crew/mhammond/win32/Downloads.html) and call Windows APIs to do that directly
2. Use a WMI-wrapper for Python

(some [WMI interface code](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/scripts/python/misc/wmi/mswmpy01.mspx?mfr=true) for reference)

*Edit*: I assumed your OS was MS Windows :)

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, look in the /proc directory.  You'll have to parse the files to find what you are looking for.

[This](http://www.linux.com/feature/126718) might help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this library: [Hardware ID Extractor](http://www.soft.tahionic.com/download-hdd_id/index.html)

---

Small description of the tool:

The Hardware ID Extractor is a Microsoft Windows program that shows data about your computer's hardware:

Hard disk:

- Hard drive ID (unique hardware serial number written in drive's IDE electronic chip)
- Partition ID (volume serial number)

CPU:

- CPU ID (unique hardware ID)
- CPU vendor
- CPU running speed
- CPU theoretic speed

Physical memory:

- Memory Load ( Total memory used in percentage (%) )
  *Total Physical ( Total physical memory in bytes )
  *Avail Physical ( Physical memory left in bytes )
  *Total PageFile ( Total page file in bytes )
  *Available PageFile( Page file left in bytes )
  *Total Virtual( Total virtual memory in bytes )
  *Available Virtual ( Virtual memory left in bytes )