# How to get hard disk serial number using Python

Tags: python, linux, hard-drive, serial-number, fcntl

How can I get the `serial number` of a `hard disk` drive using `Python` on `Linux`?

I would like to use a Python module to do that instead of running an external program such as [`hdparm`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/hdparm).  Perhaps using the [`fcntl`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) module?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

## Linux

As you suggested, [fcntl](http://docs.python.org/library/fcntl.html) is the way to do this on Linux.  The C code you want to translate looks like this:

```
static struct hd_driveid hd;
int fd;

if ((fd = open("/dev/hda", O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK)) < 0) {
    printf("ERROR opening /dev/hda\n");
    exit(1);
}

if (!ioctl(fd, HDIO_GET_IDENTITY, &hd)) {
    printf("%.20s\n", hd.serial_no);
} else if (errno == -ENOMSG) {
    printf("No serial number available\n");
} else {
    perror("ERROR: HDIO_GET_IDENTITY");
    exit(1);
}
```

Translated into Python on Ubuntu 9.10, it goes a little something like this:

```
import sys, os, fcntl, struct

if os.geteuid() >  0:
    print("ERROR: Must be root to use")
    sys.exit(1)

with open(sys.argv[1], "rb") as fd:
    # tediously derived from the monster struct defined in <hdreg.h>
    # see comment at end of file to verify
    hd_driveid_format_str = "@ 10H 20s 3H 8s 40s 2B H 2B H 4B 6H 2B I 36H I Q 152H"
    # Also from <hdreg.h>
    HDIO_GET_IDENTITY = 0x030d
    # How big a buffer do we need?
    sizeof_hd_driveid = struct.calcsize(hd_driveid_format_str)

    # ensure our format string is the correct size
    # 512 is extracted using sizeof(struct hd_id) in the c code
    assert sizeof_hd_driveid == 512 

    # Call native function
    buf = fcntl.ioctl(fd, HDIO_GET_IDENTITY, " " * sizeof_hd_driveid)
    fields = struct.unpack(hd_driveid_format_str, buf)
    serial_no = fields[10].strip()
    model = fields[15].strip()
    print("Hard Disk Model: %s" % model)
    print("  Serial Number: %s" % serial_no)


## For documentation purposes, this is the struct copied from <hdreg.h>
# struct hd_driveid {
#   unsigned short  config;     /* lots of obsolete bit flags */
#   unsigned short  cyls;       /* Obsolete, "physical" cyls */
#   unsigned short  reserved2;  /* reserved (word 2) */
#   unsigned short  heads;      /* Obsolete, "physical" heads */
#   unsigned short  track_bytes;    /* unformatted bytes per track */
#   unsigned short  sector_bytes;   /* unformatted bytes per sector */
#   unsigned short  sectors;    /* Obsolete, "physical" sectors per track */
#   unsigned short  vendor0;    /* vendor unique */
#   unsigned short  vendor1;    /* vendor unique */
#   unsigned short  vendor2;    /* Retired vendor unique */
#   unsigned char   serial_no[20];  /* 0 = not_specified */
#   unsigned short  buf_type;   /* Retired */
#   unsigned short  buf_size;   /* Retired, 512 byte increments
#                    * 0 = not_specified
#                    */
#   unsigned short  ecc_bytes;  /* for r/w long cmds; 0 = not_specified */
#   unsigned char   fw_rev[8];  /* 0 = not_specified */
#   unsigned char   model[40];  /* 0 = not_specified */
#   unsigned char   max_multsect;   /* 0=not_implemented */
#   unsigned char   vendor3;    /* vendor unique */
#   unsigned short  dword_io;   /* 0=not_implemented; 1=implemented */
#   unsigned char   vendor4;    /* vendor unique */
#   unsigned char   capability; /* (upper byte of word 49)
#                    *  3:  IORDYsup
#                    *  2:  IORDYsw
#                    *  1:  LBA
#                    *  0:  DMA
#                    */
#   unsigned short  reserved50; /* reserved (word 50) */
#   unsigned char   vendor5;    /* Obsolete, vendor unique */
#   unsigned char   tPIO;       /* Obsolete, 0=slow, 1=medium, 2=fast */
#   unsigned char   vendor6;    /* Obsolete, vendor unique */
#   unsigned char   tDMA;       /* Obsolete, 0=slow, 1=medium, 2=fast */
#   unsigned short  field_valid;    /* (word 53)
#                    *  2:  ultra_ok    word  88
#                    *  1:  eide_ok     words 64-70
#                    *  0:  cur_ok      words 54-58
#                    */
#   unsigned short  cur_cyls;   /* Obsolete, logical cylinders */
#   unsigned short  cur_heads;  /* Obsolete, l heads */
#   unsigned short  cur_sectors;    /* Obsolete, l sectors per track */
#   unsigned short  cur_capacity0;  /* Obsolete, l total sectors on drive */
#   unsigned short  cur_capacity1;  /* Obsolete, (2 words, misaligned int)     */
#   unsigned char   multsect;   /* current multiple sector count */
#   unsigned char   multsect_valid; /* when (bit0==1) multsect is ok */
#   unsigned int    lba_capacity;   /* Obsolete, total number of sectors */
#   unsigned short  dma_1word;  /* Obsolete, single-word dma info */
#   unsigned short  dma_mword;  /* multiple-word dma info */
#   unsigned short  eide_pio_modes; /* bits 0:mode3 1:mode4 */
#   unsigned short  eide_dma_min;   /* min mword dma cycle time (ns) */
#   unsigned short  eide_dma_time;  /* recommended mword dma cycle time (ns) */
#   unsigned short  eide_pio;       /* min cycle time (ns), no IORDY  */
#   unsigned short  eide_pio_iordy; /* min cycle time (ns), with IORDY */
#   unsigned short  words69_70[2];  /* reserved words 69-70
#                    * future command overlap and queuing
#                    */
#   unsigned short  words71_74[4];  /* reserved words 71-74
#                    * for IDENTIFY PACKET DEVICE command
#                    */
#   unsigned short  queue_depth;    /* (word 75)
#                    * 15:5 reserved
#                    *  4:0 Maximum queue depth -1
#                    */
#   unsigned short  words76_79[4];  /* reserved words 76-79 */
#   unsigned short  major_rev_num;  /* (word 80) */
#   unsigned short  minor_rev_num;  /* (word 81) */
#   unsigned short  command_set_1;  /* (word 82) supported
#                    * 15:  Obsolete
#                    * 14:  NOP command
#                    * 13:  READ_BUFFER
#                    * 12:  WRITE_BUFFER
#                    * 11:  Obsolete
#                    * 10:  Host Protected Area
#                    *  9:  DEVICE Reset
#                    *  8:  SERVICE Interrupt
#                    *  7:  Release Interrupt
#                    *  6:  look-ahead
#                    *  5:  write cache
#                    *  4:  PACKET Command
#                    *  3:  Power Management Feature Set
#                    *  2:  Removable Feature Set
#                    *  1:  Security Feature Set
#                    *  0:  SMART Feature Set
#                    */
#   unsigned short  command_set_2;  /* (word 83)
#                    * 15:  Shall be ZERO
#                    * 14:  Shall be ONE
#                    * 13:  FLUSH CACHE EXT
#                    * 12:  FLUSH CACHE
#                    * 11:  Device Configuration Overlay
#                    * 10:  48-bit Address Feature Set
#                    *  9:  Automatic Acoustic Management
#                    *  8:  SET MAX security
#                    *  7:  reserved 1407DT PARTIES
#                    *  6:  SetF sub-command Power-Up
#                    *  5:  Power-Up in Standby Feature Set
#                    *  4:  Removable Media Notification
#                    *  3:  APM Feature Set
#                    *  2:  CFA Feature Set
#                    *  1:  READ/WRITE DMA QUEUED
#                    *  0:  Download MicroCode
#                    */
#   unsigned short  cfsse;      /* (word 84)
#                    * cmd set-feature supported extensions
#                    * 15:  Shall be ZERO
#                    * 14:  Shall be ONE
#                    * 13:6 reserved
#                    *  5:  General Purpose Logging
#                    *  4:  Streaming Feature Set
#                    *  3:  Media Card Pass Through
#                    *  2:  Media Serial Number Valid
#                    *  1:  SMART selt-test supported
#                    *  0:  SMART error logging
#                    */
#   unsigned short  cfs_enable_1;   /* (word 85)
#                    * command set-feature enabled
#                    * 15:  Obsolete
#                    * 14:  NOP command
#                    * 13:  READ_BUFFER
#                    * 12:  WRITE_BUFFER
#                    * 11:  Obsolete
#                    * 10:  Host Protected Area
#                    *  9:  DEVICE Reset
#                    *  8:  SERVICE Interrupt
#                    *  7:  Release Interrupt
#                    *  6:  look-ahead
#                    *  5:  write cache
#                    *  4:  PACKET Command
#                    *  3:  Power Management Feature Set
#                    *  2:  Removable Feature Set
#                    *  1:  Security Feature Set
#                    *  0:  SMART Feature Set
#                    */
#   unsigned short  cfs_enable_2;   /* (word 86)
#                    * command set-feature enabled
#                    * 15:  Shall be ZERO
#                    * 14:  Shall be ONE
#                    * 13:  FLUSH CACHE EXT
#                    * 12:  FLUSH CACHE
#                    * 11:  Device Configuration Overlay
#                    * 10:  48-bit Address Feature Set
#                    *  9:  Automatic Acoustic Management
#                    *  8:  SET MAX security
#                    *  7:  reserved 1407DT PARTIES
#                    *  6:  SetF sub-command Power-Up
#                    *  5:  Power-Up in Standby Feature Set
#                    *  4:  Removable Media Notification
#                    *  3:  APM Feature Set
#                    *  2:  CFA Feature Set
#                    *  1:  READ/WRITE DMA QUEUED
#                    *  0:  Download MicroCode
#                    */
#   unsigned short  csf_default;    /* (word 87)
#                    * command set-feature default
#                    * 15:  Shall be ZERO
#                    * 14:  Shall be ONE
#                    * 13:6 reserved
#                    *  5:  General Purpose Logging enabled
#                    *  4:  Valid CONFIGURE STREAM executed
#                    *  3:  Media Card Pass Through enabled
#                    *  2:  Media Serial Number Valid
#                    *  1:  SMART selt-test supported
#                    *  0:  SMART error logging
#                    */
#   unsigned short  dma_ultra;  /* (word 88) */
#   unsigned short  trseuc;     /* time required for security erase */
#   unsigned short  trsEuc;     /* time required for enhanced erase */
#   unsigned short  CurAPMvalues;   /* current APM values */
#   unsigned short  mprc;       /* master password revision code */
#   unsigned short  hw_config;  /* hardware config (word 93)
#                    * 15:  Shall be ZERO
#                    * 14:  Shall be ONE
#                    * 13:
#                    * 12:
#                    * 11:
#                    * 10:
#                    *  9:
#                    *  8:
#                    *  7:
#                    *  6:
#                    *  5:
#                    *  4:
#                    *  3:
#                    *  2:
#                    *  1:
#                    *  0:  Shall be ONE
#                    */
#   unsigned short  acoustic;   /* (word 94)
#                    * 15:8 Vendor's recommended value
#                    *  7:0 current value
#                    */
#   unsigned short  msrqs;      /* min stream request size */
#   unsigned short  sxfert;     /* stream transfer time */
#   unsigned short  sal;        /* stream access latency */
#   unsigned int    spg;        /* stream performance granularity */
#   unsigned long long lba_capacity_2;/* 48-bit total number of sectors */
#   unsigned short  words104_125[22];/* reserved words 104-125 */
#   unsigned short  last_lun;   /* (word 126) */
#   unsigned short  word127;    /* (word 127) Feature Set
#                    * Removable Media Notification
#                    * 15:2 reserved
#                    *  1:0 00 = not supported
#                    *  01 = supported
#                    *  10 = reserved
#                    *  11 = reserved
#                    */
#   unsigned short  dlf;        /* (word 128)
#                    * device lock function
#                    * 15:9 reserved
#                    *  8   security level 1:max 0:high
#                    *  7:6 reserved
#                    *  5   enhanced erase
#                    *  4   expire
#                    *  3   frozen
#                    *  2   locked
#                    *  1   en/disabled
#                    *  0   capability
#                    */
#   unsigned short  csfo;       /*  (word 129)
#                    * current set features options
#                    * 15:4 reserved
#                    *  3:  auto reassign
#                    *  2:  reverting
#                    *  1:  read-look-ahead
#                    *  0:  write cache
#                    */
#   unsigned short  words130_155[26];/* reserved vendor words 130-155 */
#   unsigned short  word156;    /* reserved vendor word 156 */
#   unsigned short  words157_159[3];/* reserved vendor words 157-159 */
#   unsigned short  cfa_power;  /* (word 160) CFA Power Mode
#                    * 15 word 160 supported
#                    * 14 reserved
#                    * 13
#                    * 12
#                    * 11:0
#                    */
#   unsigned short  words161_175[15];/* Reserved for CFA */
#   unsigned short  words176_205[30];/* Current Media Serial Number */
#   unsigned short  words206_254[49];/* reserved words 206-254 */
#   unsigned short  integrity_word; /* (word 255)
#                    * 15:8 Checksum
#                    *  7:0 Signature
#                    */
# };
```

Apologies for the length, I thought it useful to include the original C struct as a comment.  Also, I'm pretty new to both the `fcntl` and `struct` modules, so I may be doing something unidomatic.  In anycase, run from the command-line (with root privelidges) it looks like this (I've redacted my exact serial for privacy):

```
fmark@fmark-laptop:~/Desktop/hdserial$ sudo python hd.py "/dev/sda"
Hard Disk Model: FUJITSU MHV2080BH PL
  Serial Number: NW--------
```

#### What's going on here?

In order to be able to understand what is going on here, you need to look at the `#include <linux/hdreg.h>` in the original C program.  This include imports the `HDIO_GET_IDENTITY` constant and the  `struct hd_driveid`.  I've copied the struct as a comment into the python sourcecode above, so I won't repeat it here.  To find out what is going on with `HDIO_GET_IDENTITY`, grep the source-code for it (on Ubuntu this is at `/usr/include/linux/hdreg.h`.  You should find something like this:

```
 #define HDIO_GET_IDENTITY       0x030d  /* get IDE identification info */
```

Thus, you find that `HDIO_GET_IDENTITY` is just a constant that tells fcntl that you are interested in getting HD info.  As you will notice, that same value (`0x030d` is an integer in hexadecimal notation) is assigned to a variable in the python code.

## Windows

I realise now you are interested in Linux, but I'll keep this here for posterity.  The following will get the HDD serial number on Windows (you will need to install the [wmi package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/WMI/)):

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI()
for item in c.Win32_PhysicalMedia():
    print item
```

Answer (score 4):

Get a screwdriver and open the case ;-)

If you are on windows, this might do the trick

```
import win32api
print win32api.GetVolumeInformation("C:\\")
```

For this you need the Mark Hammond modules for windows
http://python.net/crew/mhammond/

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, you can also get it using `subprocess`, which is built-in!

```
import subprocess

serials = subprocess.check_output('wmic diskdrive get SerialNumber').decode().split('\n')[1:]
serials = [s.strip() for s in serials if s.strip()]
```

If you also want other information such as index and manufacturer:

```
import subprocess

serials = subprocess.check_output('wmic diskdrive get Index, SerialNumber, Manufacturer').decode().split('\n')[1:]
```

For a list of available properties, check [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-diskdrive).

Answer (score 1):

### Windows

```
def get_serial_number_of_physical_disk(drive_letter='C:'):
    import wmi
    
    c = wmi.WMI()
    logical_disk = c.Win32_LogicalDisk(Caption=drive_letter)[0]
    partition = logical_disk.associators()[1]
    physical_disc = partition.associators()[0]
    return physical_disc.SerialNumber
```

For example:

```
get_serial_number_of_physical_disk(os.getenv('SystemDrive'))
```

will give you serial number of disk that contains logical system drive.

Answer (score 0):

for Windows

```
import os
data = os.popen('vol '+'c:', 'r').read()
data = data.split()
print(data[len(data)-1:])
```