# How can i get detailed information about hdd on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

How i can get information about hdd. Such as manufacturer, model, type and etc? Maybe someone know any library. Please don't tell me: "Search in Google". Forgot to mention. I need to find out with the help of Python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get hard disk serial number using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193514/how-to-get-hard-disk-serial-number-using-python)

Comment: It's serial number, but i want to know all information about hdd.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. It's library WMI. Class Win32_DiskDrive.

Answer (score -1):

```
FROM Boot up menu , press f12 or f10 while booting you will find it there.
```

Comment: Please add context to your answer explaining how this is a solution to the problem. Thanks! --From Review