# CPU identifier under windows, gnu/linux, macosx

Tags: windows, linux, macos, cpu

In order to recognize a computer in a certain manner (MAC adress not appropriate for some cases, disk ID or hostname neither etc.), I would like to **detect a CPU id** (or first CPU core id)... How can I achieve this on different platforms? (not necessarily in manner that is robust to OS change on the same computer)

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to recognize the computers, for what purpose?

Comment: For a shameful purpose (kill kittens and puppies...)

Comment: See my answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461141/get-a-unique-computer-id-in-python-on-windows-and-linux/2462978#2462978

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CPU id identifies the processor model, and isn't unique to each computer.  See:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID

The MAC address is usually the best way to uniquely identify a system.

Comment: Indeed, but a CPU changes less often than an ethernet or wifi card, and there is always at least one, and the cores don't change of order between starts. An argument which does not give credit to you nor me: a MAC address can easily be spoofed (as much as a CPU id, without any doubt).

Comment: I would not say that mac address is the best way, it is by far the easiest one to spoof.

Comment: But CPUIDs aren't unique -- all the systems with the same model Intel processor will have the same CPUID.  What am I missing?

Comment: Indeed, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_III#Controversy_about_privacy_issues too bad