# Python (maybe sys or os module) to get a unique identifier of client's machine

Tags: python

I want to use (maybe `os` or `sys` module or any other module) python to get a unique identifier of the client. Such as CPU number or anything else that is fixed and never changes. How is this possible?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about asking about writing code on someone's behalf, not fixing a specific programming issue.

Comment: How so?  Looks like a completely legitimate question to me.

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a look to

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyCPUID

or to this question: [Get a unique computer ID in Python on windows and linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461141/get-a-unique-computer-id-in-python-on-windows-and-linux)