# how to get a secure unique identifier from multiple pieces of hardware using python?

Tags: python, mongodb, raspberry-pi

Say I have a hundred(possibility thousands) of connected raspberry pi and these pi will emit a message though tcpip to a mongo data base when they get online.   This message will be a unique id that will register the device inside of mongodb.

Question: is there a unique number that is secure that I can just emit to a database as a unique id or will there have to be some kind of back and forth?

Comment: you want exact identical id to specify machine or just a uuid? have a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html.

Comment: Not a uuid because none of the machines will know of another.  Unless I make a handshake between the db and machines.  Therefore I want a identical Id to specify a machine that won't conflict with other machines; moreover each machine will only know of itself

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461141/get-a-unique-computer-id-in-python-on-windows-and-linux. it seems you just need MAC address. it seems this one is even easier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159137/getting-mac-address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To identify the PI(s), I'd use/send the serial number(s) [(`cat /proc/cpuinfo`)](http://www.raspberrypi.com/mpeg-2-license-key/). It's used to make money, so the manufacturer won't tolerate duplicates.

See ["Getting Your Raspberry Pi Serial Number Using Python"](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2012/09/getting-your-raspberry-pi-serial-number-using-python/) for Python and further background.

The MAC address identifies a component that could change (e.g. WiFi dongle).