# HWID Binded Whitelist System | Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So say I want to make a software using python that you have to purchase. How would I make a system that gives users a "whitelist code" which they can use to gain access to my software. This code however, needs to be one-time use and HWID binded. I am not an expert python developer by any means so I have no idea where to begin with such a task.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here, I hope this helps you!

```
hwid = str(subprocess.check_output(
    'wmic csproduct get uuid')).split('\\r\\n')[1].strip('\\r').strip()
data = requests.get(
    'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rishav394/z/raw/x')
if hwid in data.text:
    print('Authenticated!')
    auth = True
else:
    print(hwid + ' was not found on the server.\nNot authorised!')
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55798376/14410859