# How can I get the actual hardware ID/UUID of connected sound devices in Python?

Tags: python, audio, uuid, hardware

Is there a library or subprocess command I can use to get the hardware ID/UUID in Python?  I would like to check to see what audio output devices are on the system and then select one and save that UUID for later so if I open the program up again or plug in different devices it can still know to go out over the correct device.  I tried using the sounddevice library but it seems like that can only get the current hardware ID (which can change).  Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a unique computer ID in Python on windows and linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461141/get-a-unique-computer-id-in-python-on-windows-and-linux)

Comment: It looks like that is getting the UUID of the computer itself, not a way to retrieve a list of audio devices id's/uuid's