# How do I use Python to prevent a file from being copied?

Tags: python, windows, file, copy

I have a file that I need to "protect" so that it cannot be copied! I am using Python on Windows XP.

I think it may just be changing file permissions??

Comment: To prevent a *copy* you must prevent *all read access*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent the file being copied only by removing read permission from the user that shouldn't be able to copy the file. You can use `os.chmod` for this, or see [this page](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/add-security-to-a-file.html) explaining to set permissions with the full Windows security model.

Comment: Would my software still be able to read from it? How do I do this in Python?

Comment: If your software runs as a special user, you can make sure only that user has read access to the file. I updated the answer with a link to a page that describes how to set advanced permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a temporary or a permanent file? If it's temporary, take a look at the [`tempfile`](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html) module, especially `tempfile.mkstemp()`.

Comment: No, it is a permanent file. It is a file that I will place on the drive to tell my software that it is registered and a valid copy. That is why I need to make sure it cannot be copied.

Comment: OK, so your software licence is on a per-machine basis, not a per-user-basis, then? Why not connect the licence to a physical feature of the machine then, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227222/how-can-you-extract-hardware-id-using-python - but also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473143/methods-to-stop-software-piracy.